# Как можно сделать более красивое форматирование?

Tags: reactjs

```
<div className="catalog-mobile__counter" key={cart.find(item => item.product._id === product._id) ? cart.find(item => item.product._id === product._id).quantity : "" }>
              <div className="catalog-mobile__minus"></div>
              <input type="text" defaultValue={cart.find(item => item.product._id === product._id) ? cart.find(item => item.product._id === product._id).quantity : "" } />
              <div className="catalog-mobile__plus"></div>
          </div>
```

Как можно сделать рефактор данного кода. Тут условная проврека ибо не все пункты выдают результат и за чего некоторые undefined и ошибка , поэтому так, но выглядит ужасно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы на Вашем месте вынес бы эти вычисления с `JSX`. А там где `key` дал что-то вроде `id` или уникального значения. Есть предположение, что `quantity` - может повторится. Для того, чтобы сократить код можно использовать [Optional chaining](https://learn.javascript.ru/optional-chaining).

```
const cartQuantity = cart.find(item => item.product._id === product._id)?.quantity || '';

return (
    <div className="catalog-mobile__counter" key={cartQuantity}>
        <div className="catalog-mobile__minus"></div>
        <input type="text" defaultValue={cartQuantity} />
        <div className="catalog-mobile__plus"></div>
    </div>
)
```

В случае, если у Вас ошибка при работе с babel, установите следующий компонент [[Подробнее]](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining):

```
  npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я правда пытался изначально переменную поставить в самом return {const} но и за этого выдавала ошибку. Поставил до return после map и все хорошо заработал, спасибо)